# Are methods within a function object not implicitly linked as a member?

Tags: javascript

semi-novice programmer here (on and off with C++ for years, dabbling with C# mostly with Unity) and when creating objects and methods within objects it's to be expected that that method is a member of that object.

If I create a new object I can access the function with dot notation object.method.

For Javascript it appears that isn't the case?

I read somewhere about it being something like a first class object (not sure what that means) and I have to explicitly say that the method is a part of the object.

So for example in JS

```
function testObject() {

    let x = whatever;

    function testMethod() {
    }
}
```

Is a failure, it will not work.  testObject has no idea testMethod is a member.
I have to use

```
this.testMethod = function() {}
```

before it can be registered.

I just want to be sure cause I can't really find much info even from youtube videos and websites.
I want to fully grasp knowledge of why for once instead of just shrugging my shoulders and just letting it be.

If what I've stated is true can someone give me a heads up why JS is different in this regard?  And if there are any other pitfalls with JS objects that I might not notice from a C programmer background.

Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks for the comments.  This is also why programming can be such a pain.  you look for info, want to delve into it and get such conflicting information.  If you google does javascript have classes, first thing you'll see is javascript doesn't have classes (well this is obviously a lie delving deeper).  Why say that when it is provably false?  Don't care if it's not class based.  Don't say there are no classes (Not you specifically just shouting out to the internet).

I know how to declare an object literal and was looking at the youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFmuCDHHpwk&list=PLTjRvDozrdlxEIuOBZkMAK5uiqp8rHUax&index=2
to brush up on the basics, get my head back in the game and learn a new language.  Doubled down on researching just what it all means and it's sticking for once (but I digress).  He discusses about Object literals then changes his code into something similar that I presented thag he called a function object.

Is that not a thing?
Am I doing it wrong?
Apparently what I have is not an object?
Though the definition of an object is a group of data in a single unit which includes member variables and methods that work on that data.
Should I forget what I'm seeing and just stick with object literals?

Comment: That's not a class, that's just a function with a scoped function inside. It doesn't even return an object.

Comment: Well there are no classes in JS.  But I think I get what your saying.  Completely forgot about the whole classes thing.  Since I've not declared a class, the object has no idea about it's members.  I was under the impression it was automatic.  As you can tell I'm rather rusty.

Comment: There are [classes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: @D.Pardal Maybe it's a constructor function, `new testObject`, although it doesn't create any properties and doesn't follow the naming convention (`TestObject`)

Comment: No, JS is not very different in that regard. There are many languages where when you declare a function, all you get is a local variable holding the function. Only in very specific syntactic contexts, a method definition will make the function become a member of an object.

Comment: typing "object oriented JavaScript for beginners" into a search engine, pretty directly gives ones eyes something like that ... [Introducing JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects) where one gets linked to [Object-oriented JavaScript for beginners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)